# Detect When Status Bar Re-Appears

Tags: java, android, statusbar, samsung-mobile, android-fullscreen

My app runs in fullscreen (immersive mode).

The status bar is hidden at the top.

On some Samsung phones, there is a stylus pen. If the pen is removed, the status bar re-appears and won't go away.

I tried adding a listener for this event but it doesn't get called.

```
 View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.

                            System.out.print("Change event");
                        } else {
                            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            System.out.print("Change event");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Do you know how I can know if the status bar has re-appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my activity I do this to get it re-hide the status bar:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        System.out.println("Gotcha");
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hiding");
                _root.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
            }
        }, 6000);
    }
```